# Which conic section does z represent?

Tags: complex-numbers, conic-sections

> If a,b,c,d are four complex numbers such that  $c/d$ is real and ad-bc
>   is not equal to 0.z is defined as $\dfrac{a+bt}{c+dt}$ where t is a real
>   number.Which conic section does z represent?

My approach:

$\dfrac{a+bt}{c+dt} =\dfrac{b(a/b+t)}{d(c/d+t)} = b/d,$ if $(ad-bc)=0$.

That would represent a single point in the Argand plane.What's next?

Comment: Why not say  $ Z = \dfrac{z_1+z_2 a}{z_3+z_4 a} $ and so on?

Comment: Yes you can. @Narasimham

Comment: I'm confused. The problem statement requires $ad-bc\neq0$ whereas your approach assumes the opposite.

Comment: @JanStout I just tried to see what happens when ad=bc..that's all..not being able to approach the problem directly.